# Scheduled IOS local notifications repeat every minute

Tags: ios, swift4, uilocalnotification

I have an IOS app that schedules a local notification on the day the app is opened, and every day at roughly the same time for the next 7 days. What happens is each notification is repeated the number of days I schedule for, so in this case each notification is repeated 8 times, one per minute on each day rather than one each day for 8 days. I thought it may be due to the identifier but i have tried to make that as unique as possible, heres my code:

Where scheduleDate is an array of Dates that I loop over:

```
func getNextNDays(numberOfDays: Int) -> [Date] {
    let today = Date()
    var days = [Date]()
        
    for i in 1...numberOfDays {
        let nextNDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: today) ?? Date()
        days.append(nextNDay)
    }
        
    return days
}

let numberOfDaysForNotifications = 7
let nextNDays = getNextNDays(numberOfDays: numberOfDaysForNotifications)

for nextDate in nextNDays {
    scheduleNotification(scheduleDate: nextDate)
}

// nextNDays contains
[2021-04-15 17:03:54 +0000, 2021-04-16 17:03:54 +0000, 2021-04-17 17:03:54 +0000, 2021-04-18 17:03:54 +0000, 2021-04-19 17:03:54 +0000, 2021-04-20 17:03:54 +0000, 2021-04-21 17:03:54 +0000]
```

```
func scheduleNotification(scheduleDate: Date) {
    let date = scheduleDate
    let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Some title"
    content.body = "Some body"
    content.badge = 0
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HHmmEdMMMy"

    let identifier = notificationTitle + formatter.string(from: scheduleDate) + UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error scheduling notification \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: You have shown how you schedule a single notification, but can you show the code where you schedule the series of notifications?

Comment: hi Paul I've updated the question

Comment: You are scheduling new notifications with unique identifiers each time you run this code. Because the identifiers are unique new notifications will be scheduled along with those previously scheduled. You should cancel all existing notifications before scheduling new ones

Comment: I do by calling this: UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() - however that wouldn't explain why I get the same notification 7 times (one each each minute on the scheduled time) rather than one a day for 7 days ?

Comment: Your trigger components are only hour, minute and second. You need to include the date as well as the time, otherwise all 7 notification triggers match today.

Comment: You're right, thanks Paul - add this as the answer so I can accept